# Redefine trait for infix operators

Tags: rust, traits, infix-operator

I'm trying to redefine the `Add` trait so that I could use it as infix operator:

```rust
//use std::ops::Add;

trait Add<RHS=Self> {
    // type Output;

    fn add(self, rhs: RHS) -> Self;
}

fn summ<T: Add>(a: T, b: T) -> T {  
    a+b
}  // doesn't compile
```

Is it possible to redefine the `Add` trait so that it will use the `+` operator for add functionality?

Comment: Why are you trying to redefine the trait? The standard `Add` trait already provides overloading on the binary `+` operator.

Comment: because the standard Add uses associated type Output - that it's a piece I don't want to use. If you look at the def. of my function, you could see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to redefine any traits. You could create your own trait with the same name and same methods, which is what you have done. However, the operator `+` is tied to `std::ops::Add`, so it wouldn't be useful in this case.

In your case, it looks like you just want to specify `Add::Output` to return a `T`:

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn summ<T>(a: T, b: T) -> T
    where T: Add<Output = T>
{  
    a + b
}
```

Comment: thanks - that solves the problem. Beautiful solution -  kudos.